# Hot Water Heater Pressure Relief Valve Hissing and Discharging Water after Draining Tank

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, hot-water

I just drained the hot water heater, as I do every year (using the following video for instructions: https://youtu.be/qqaehhGYV_I). This time, the pressure relief valve had a slight hiss after I refilled the tank and closed the valve.

I noticed today the discharge valve on the side of the house is spewing hot water continously from the hot water heater.

Do I need to replace the pressure relief valve, or what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes when you open older valves, they get stuck open. If you can't get the valve to reset, you'll have to replace it.

Comment: Yes, try opening and closing the valve to see if it will re-seal itself.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Tried and it didn't work. Going to have to replace.

Comment: Bummer, yeah it is probably scaled up with lime over the years.

Comment: Valve replaced and no more leaks. Lots of buildup inside the old valve.